# How can I debug a RuntimeError on ActiveRecord Query with Custom Joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to translate a working SQL statement to ActiveRecord query.  Below is the current query I have setup but when I execute it I am getting the following error, any can help me figure out steps to debug this?

**Error**

```
RuntimeError: unknown class: Fixnum
```

**Query**

```
Contestant.joins('INNER JOIN votes AS V on V.contestant_id = contestants.id LEFT JOIN votes as XV on XV.contestant_id = (?) and XV.tribal_council_key = V.tribal_council_key and XV.contestant_voted_for_id = V.contestant_voted_for_id', self.id)
                  .where('V.is_jury_vote = (?) AND V.contestant_id <> (?)', :false, self.id)
                  .group('V.contestant_id')
                  .having('count(XV.tribal_council_key) > (?)', :false)
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best way of doing it but I changed my `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  Instead of using `(?)` to set the id, I went ahead and used `'+ self.id.to_s +'`.